# What is Z in a 3D universe?

Tags: java, 3d, cube

I'm creating a 3D renderer in Java, which currently can render the wireframe of a cube using Points and lines and rotate the cube, the question is, what should Z be? And what should be set to Z? I'm guessing that the size of the cube should be set to Z?

Thanks for your time! Any answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be missing some basic school math/geometry here. However, it's actually not that hard to understand.

Imagine a flat plane, e.g. a sheet of paper.

- The first coordinate axis will go straight from left to right and we'll call it X. So X = 0 means your point is on the left border. X = 10 might mean your point is on the right border (really depends on how big you define a unit of 1; this could be in centimeters, inches, etc.). This is already enough to describe some point in one dimension (from left to right).
- Now, we need a second axis. Let's call it Y. It's running from the top border (Y = 0) to the bottom (Y = 10). Now you're able to describe any point on the plane as you've got two positions. For example, (0, 0) would be the top left corner. (10, 10) would be the bottom right corner. (5, 0) would be the center point of the top border, etc.
- What happens if we add yet another dimension? Call it Z. This will essentially be the height of your point above the sheet. For example, Z = 0 could mean your point is sitting on the sheet of painter, while Z = 10 means your point is sitting 10 cm above the paper. Now you use three coordinates to describe a point: (5, 5, 0) is the center of the paper. (5,5,5) is the center of the cube sitting on your paper filling it and being 10 cm high.

When programming in 3D, you can use the same terminology. The only real difference is, that you're using a so called projection/view matrix to determine how to display this 3d positions on screen. The easiest transform could be the following matrix:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

Multiplying this with your 3d coordinates you'll get the following two terms:

2d-x = 3d-x
2d-y = 3d-y

This results in you viewing the cube (or whatever you're trying to display) from straight above essentially ignoring the Z axis again (you can't render something sticking out of your display, unless using some kind of 3d glasses or similar technology).

---

Overall, it's up to you how you use the coordinates and interpret them. Usually x and y refer to the plane (position on the ground or position inside a 2D world) while z might be the height or the depth (front or back). It really depends on the specific case. But in generic, it's really just another dimension like x and y.

Comment: This is really helpful, but also when rendering the cube, do you set the size of the cube to Z? so the bigger Z is, the bigger the cube is?

Comment: It really depends on your coordinates. Forget about the third dimension and think with basic 2D geometry/school math. You define 4 points to form a rectangle. Based on where they are, a bigger coordinate might mean a smaller or bigger resulting rectangle. It's the same for the third dimension. Based on your rotation, the size of the object is no longer based on a single coordinate. If not rotated, x might define the position from the left as well as the width. In a similar way, y might define the position from the top or bottom (based on your origin) as well as the height of the rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

Z usually means the out-of-plane direction if the current viewport lies in the x-y plane.

Your 3D world has its own coordinate system.  You'll transform from 3D world coordinates to viewport coordinates when you render.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about out of plane direction? What is the plane and the direction?

Comment: Imagine your 3D world sitting on a sheet of paper or your screen. The coordinate system is completely up to you. There are defaults (e.g. left handed vs. right handed system), but you're not forced to use any specific convention. Back to the sheet or the screen. You could define that X goes from left to right, Y from up to down and then Z would be from the screen towards you.

Comment: Actually, that would be a left-handed coordinate system.  The cross-product of X into Y should give you the Z direction.  That means the origin in the upper right corner, X pointing to the left, Y pointing down, and Z out of the screen towards the user.

Answer (score 2):

3D means 3 "Dimensions".  One dimension is "X", the other "Y", the third "Z". None have a sepcific direction, though it's convenient to conventionally assign a direction, for example "Forward", "Left", and "Up".

Something whose X, Y, and Z values are all equal to 0 resides at the *origin*, or center of the space. You can write this as (0,0,0) where the order of the parameters are (x,y,z).

A point or vertex at the location (1,0,0) is one unit in the X direction from the origin. So if you moved from (0,0,0) to (1,0,0), you would be moving purely in the X direction.

(0,1,0) is one unit in the Y direction away from the origin.

(0,0,1) is one unit in the Z direction away from the origin.

(1,1,0) is one unit in the X direction and one unit in the Y direction.  So if X means "Forward", and Y means "Left", then (1,1,0) is forward-and-left of the origin.

So a basic cube can be defined by the following vertices:

```
(1,1,-1)
(1,-1,-1)
(-1,1,-1)
(-1,-1,-1)
(1,1,1)
(1,-1,1)
(-1,1,1)
(-1,-1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I'm asking is, how should I use Z? Set the size of the cube to Z? Or other ways?

Comment: One example is, if your computer screen goes from (0,0) in the top left, to (800,600) in the bottom right, the point (400,300,0) is in the center of your screen, on the surface. (400,300,-100) is in the center of your screen, but "in" slightly (i.e. a few inches further from your face than the surface of the monitor). (400,300,+100) is "out" slightly (i.e. a few inches closer to your face than the monitor).  In a 3D game, you typically can't 'see' things that are sticking "out" of the monitor, as they are "behind" the camera, so they are simply not drawn. +/- 100 in this example is the "Z".